# Java, menuBar, JMenuitems Focus

Tags: java, swing

I have created JMenuItems with Key Accelerators, then i have added them to the menubar directly without the need to be added to the JMenu so they look like JButtons, every thing work just fine, but i noticed that JMenuItem never get focus when clicked or key pressed, that make some problems to me for example:
One of the JMenuItems is for save, also i have one JTextField which do some validation when losing focus, but that not working since when pressing the Save, the focus kept there on the JTextField.

Any Ideas ?!

Comment: And what's wrong with a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)?

Comment: JToolBar !! OK but i need the JMenuItem Since i can use the key accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `JToolBar` and taking advantage of the Action API

Here's a really short example of how you might be able to achieve accelerator support for toolbar (or any) button.

```
public class MenuTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MenuTest();
    }

    public MenuTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
                tb.add(new FastButton(new OpenAction()));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FastButton extends JButton {

        private FastButton(Action action) {
            super(action);
            setHideActionText(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configurePropertiesFromAction(Action a) {
            super.configurePropertiesFromAction(a);
            if (a != null) {
                KeyStroke ks = (KeyStroke) a.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY);
                InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
                inputMap.put(ks, "Action.accelerator");
                actionMap.put("Action.accelerator", a);
            }
        }

    }

    public class OpenAction extends AbstractAction {

        public OpenAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Open");
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
            putValue(SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/folder_document.png")));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Open");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what i really need is just setting focus on the jmenuitem when i press it, with my solution i have less code than this one, it's a great code which you have wrote here but could you help me in how to make the jmenuitem getting the focus?

Comment: `setFocusable`, `setFocusPainted` - The `JMenuItem` is designed for what you are trying to do with it, so expect problems

Comment: *"`JMenuItem` is designed for what you are trying to do with it, so expect problems"*